# Is there a difference between NaCl or table salt (processed) and salt from the Himalayas?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, food-chemistry

So, I was doing some research on bonding and electronegativity and one of the examples used was NaCl (Sodium Chloride) which is salt. We don't buy processed salt, rather we buy salt from the Himalayas.

[image]

Apparently this is better salt because it is not processed, made, etc. 
But, is there a difference between NaCl and Himalayan salt in regards to their molecular structure?

Comment: Exactly why would processing something to make it consistently pure and free from potentially dangerous ingredients make it *worse*?

Comment: @matt_black "better" can mean a lot of things. It could have better taste, less environmental impact, etc. (I don't know if it does, just giving examples). It's not clear to me what OP meant by it.

Comment: Typically, the people making claims like "Apparently this is better salt because it is not processed, made, etc." are the ones selling the stuff. A little skepticism is warranted.

Comment: I'm guessing one important difference is the price.

Comment: @matt_black processing or purification can add impurities of chemicals used to purify the desired chemical, e.g. organic solvents, metallic catalysts etc. So it can happen that you removed one impurity and added the other. Of course, I don't want to get into regulations of food processing here, but it is a thing to consider

Comment: Since it's  a different colour, what makes you doubt for an instant that it's different? Clearly there's *something* in those crystals other than a regular NaCl lattice, so when you say "in regards to their molecular structure", what are you really asking about?

Comment: @matt_black, I think your question was answered by user2829 -

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen Sure, processing *can* introduce impurities, but food products are highly regulated and usually don't. The claim that it is better *because* it isn't processed is ridiculous as many *natural* things contain dangerous or poisonous ingredients.

Comment: @matt_black - Right, but in the case of Himalayan salt, usually there isnt anything poisonous.

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen Possibly, but that isn't a given and you can't be sure without analysis. Being natural is irrelevant and some natural salts clearly contain heavy metal contaminants as DavePhD points out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No salt will be pure NaCl.  Each will have some degree of other elements.  The fact that the salt isn't white confirms there are other elements present.

See [Analysis of Gourmet Salts for the
Presence of Heavy Metals](http://www.spexcertiprep.com/knowledge-base/files/AppNote_GourmetSalts.pdf) which investigates 14 salts including two Himalayan salts.

See especially "Table 3. Comparison of toxic elements in Table Salt".

A "Himalayan Pink Fine Mineral Salt" was found to have the highest level of cadmium and tied for first for the highest level of nickel.

NaCl isn't molecular, but instead is a [lattice of Na+ and Cl- ions](http://departments.kings.edu/chemlab/animation/nacl.html).  Other ions can lie within this lattice as impurities.

Comment: Wait, so Himalayan salt is more toxic than processed salt?

Comment: @VPrime not necessarily, but if it isn't white or colorless it's obvious that there is other stuff in there.  The reference says in the toxic elements section "highest concentration of
elements were found in the darker or deeply colored
salts".

Comment: *"No salt will be pure NaCl."* - Do you mean nothing in the grocery store is pure NaCl?

Comment: @Era It's somewhere between 97% and 99.7% pure.  We have another question about that http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24816/how-pure-nacl-is-typical-table-salt-how-is-it-purified

Comment: @Era Salt for human consumption (in the developed world, at least) is also deliberately [idodised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodised_salt).  The grocery store salt you're talking about has iodine "impurities" added deliberately, in addition to the general truism that nothing's 100% pure.

Comment: @HopelessN00b not really, "the World Health Organization’s (WHO) European Region has been identified as having the lowest coverage of salt iodization of all the regions." http://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/micronutrients/iodine_deficiency/9789241593960/en/

Comment: @HopelessN00b Kosher salt might be almost pure. It at least usually does not contain intentionally added iodine, but it could contain other impurities.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Pickling salt is also generally iodine-free.  You can get uniodized salt, yes, but at least in North America, (and some, but not all, European countries, apparently) it's something you have to look for.

Comment: Iodine is added to our salt because it is a necessary nutrient for our bodies, but in some parts of the world there is no natural or sufficient source of Iodine. Same way, in some other parts of the world you can find table salts with added iron.

Comment: @DavePhD - so you are saying that NaCl is more 'pure' than himalayan salt and therefore would have less elements? If so, would it be plausible to say that Himalayan salt is therefore more beneficial than NaCl?
P.S. Are you also saying that the color of the salt gives a general idea of how many elements there are in the salt? E.G. Himalayan salt is pink, thus would it be logical to assume that Himalayan elements > than those in NaCl?

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen I'm not saying salt is automatically less pure because it comes from the Himalayas.  That's a huge region and there are probably lots of different mines with each mine having different salt, even different parts of the same mine would have differenced.  Heck, even the individual grains in the photo have visible differences from each other.  Unless you actually analyze the salt, who knows what's in it?

Comment: @DavePhD, right. I am asking my questions in a more general sense. 
Is NaCl more 'pure' - can you derive to this conclusion from its color? 
Would you say that Himalayan salt (in general) would have more elements in it and could you say that its color can give you that impression?

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen “NaCl” refers a molecule composed of one sodium atom, and chlorine atom, and nothing else. A substance is “purely” NaCl when it consists of only this type of molecule, and nothing else. So when you ask “is NaCl more ‘pure’?” the answer is, by definition, yes—you have defined the substance as being of a particular type of molecule, and have indicated that this is all it is composed of. But you seem to be using “NaCl” to mean “processed table salt” which is not quite true: processed table salt is *mostly* NaCl, but nothing in practice is 100% pure, plus many places add iodine.

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen So table salt is mostly NaCl, possibly with some iodine, and then very small amounts (0.3% - 3% to use DavePhD’s numbers) of whatever else. It is therefore 97% “pure NaCl.” And since NaCl is white, something that is 97% NaCl is probably white (and is in the case of table salt). Something like the Himalayan salt, that is mostly NaCl but visibly not white, must have some larger amount of something else to give it that color: it must be less “purely NaCl” than table salt. So yes, the color of the Himalayan salt indicates that there is more than just NaCl molecules in it.

Comment: @KRyan Ahhh, I see. Thanks a lot for your clarifications - I can better understand this now!

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen Sure, you could say that, though it’s almost a circular statement: the purest form of NaCl is NaCl itself. Well, yes. Processed table salt, at least when it isn’t iodized or “iron-ized” or whatever, is “supposed to be” NaCl, so it’s 100% pure when only NaCl molecules are present, at which point we could accurately call it just NaCl instead of table salt (which in reality is a more complex mixture of mostly NaCl but also some other things). But if we were talking about water, that’s “supposed to be” H₂O, so adding NaCl makes it less pure.

Answer (score 11):

You've already fallen to the marketing. Take a step back and ask yourself - how would a processed X be better then natural X? In many cases, you'll find advantages and disadvantages to both approaches. And don't forget that "natural" can kill you just as easily as "industrial" - you don't even have to go to outright poisions like death caps. A lot of the food we eat all the time is poisonous without proper processing - potatoes or rhubarb, for example. In other cases, we're outright trying to get those poisons in our food - chocolate, coffee, tobacco; of course, we're  calculating how much of the poison is appropriate to get the desired behaviour (good taste, "drug effect") while limiting damage. Humans are actually pretty tolerant to huge amounts of different poisons - the ones that are left are usually very serious indeed :)

But you can be sure that "molecular structure of NaCl" will always be the same - it's entirely determined by the laws of physics. There's been some crackpottery about ideas like "water memory" or "changing angle between atoms in water" - that's just pure hogwash playing on people who didn't pick up much of Chemistry in high school, so I feel I have to stress that. What might be different is composition (impurities in addition to the NaCl) and crystal structure (pure NaCl in a well made crystal is very optically transparent, the pink colour of Himalayian salt is due to impurities).

Processed salt in particular is something humans have done for thousands of years (in fact, the ancient Greeks and Arabs burned oil for salt processing :)). The technologically simplest way to make salt is by letting salt water evaporate - this was commonly used in places where sunlight and other power sources (mostly rock oil) were plentiful. However, salt water is far from being pure NaCl indeed - there's plenty of other salts involved, as well as various other contaminants. These contribute to the colour and taste of the salt produced.

The purest "natural" salts were formed when whole seas evaporated - in Europe, this is mostly the Middle-terranean, of course. That was the source of many salt deposits that were extensively mined in Europe. Since such huge volumes and areas evaporated, the different salts precipitated out of the solution at different times and in different places, so you'll find quite pure "rock salt" formations - 85% and upwards is quite typical.

"Refined" salt is produced by purifying salt sources - the resulting salt might be up to about 99.75% NaCl or so. The source for the refining might be anything from sea water to rock salt to "whatever salty thing came by".

So unless the refining process itself introduces harmful impurities, refined salt will be much more pure NaCl. Is that a good thing? I don't know. There's certainly nothing inherently good or bad about purity - perhaps the other impurities are useful (iodine); perhaps they are harmful (kidney stones fun :P). And that's what you should think about when considering marketing claims such as "Himalayian salt is better because it's not processed". Processing is generally a good thing - you probably prefer your meat cooked, and your vegetables devoid of *E. Coli*, don't you? Just like home processing, industrial processing can make things better or worse, or a mixture of both. That's just the way the world works :)

If you find that you like the taste of Himalayian salt, that's the impurities talking (assuming you can actually tell the difference from a placebo). Nothing inherently bad about that, enjoy yourself ;) And don't forget that it can also be human-made for a good bit of profit :P